# Openlayers - Vector layer polygon doesn't move in-synch with Google V3 baselayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

When a polygon is drawn on the map and  the map is dragged, the position of the polygon relative to the GM V3 base changes.

```
function init() {
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Satellite",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
    );
    drawVctr = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Vector");
    map.addLayers([gsat, drawVctr]);

    // Google.v3 uses EPSG:900913 as projection, so we have to
    // transform our coordinates    
    var lng = "-71.118004"; 
    var lat =  "42.389118"; 
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 19);
    drawPlygn = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
        drawVctr,
        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon
    );      
    map.addControl(drawPlygn);
}
```

Comment: Don't want to mark this as a dupe since I'd like to actually see this issued fixed and there's lots of good info here.  If this question is resolved then we can close the other as well.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/openlayers-and-google-maps-when-panning-tiles-not-in-sync

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue has been [reported and closed](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/618), marked with a comment that it cannot be fixed unless Google Maps fixes an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2189) on their end. I on the other hand, believe it is fixable by using [MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject)'s bindTo. I'll start the conversation on the closed github issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Chrome ?

If yes, let me know, I have a hint this may be related to a known problem for Chrome.

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/392

best regards,

Comment: This issue is across all browsers, and is due to a delay of Google Maps and OpenLayers staying in sync.