# OpenLayers and Google Maps when panning tiles not in sync

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to overlay WMS tiles on Google maps using the following scales 
1:287 / 1:573 / 1:1146 / 1:2292  (layer preview in geoserver)

I set a bounding box and a centroid for a specific area to set the google map as base layer.

However as I zoom or move the mouse my overlayed tile moves along, losing focus (when panning tiles not in sync).

Is there a way to resolve this?

(i am using openlayers vs 2.1/geoserver 2.1.4)

Answer (score 2):

In Short - No.

The new Google Maps v3 ToS require to use the API rather than the tiles directly. Thus, when you pan an OL map, there's a slight delay where the OL code has to pass a message to the Goog javascript API which then pans it's own map.

Whereas if we were using tiles directly, OL would pan the image tiles itself.

This is a known issue with no known legal workarounds.  There are solutions out there that tap into the Google tiles directly, but I won't reference them.

We faced the same problem with the OL 2.12/Goog v3 combo with no resolution.

Comment: Do you imply that resolving this issue may violate google's terms of use?

Comment: I don't imply. I'm stating that with certainty :)  There are tickets in OL that provide the solution and then the OL admins rolled back those changes due to collision with Google's terms.

Comment: I havent worked with microsoft or nokia api, is this an  issue with their api as well ? If yes are you aware if any possible solutions violate their terms of use?

Comment: You can access Bing tiles directly (OL does that for you), but now you have to use Bing v7 and have an API key.  I have no experience with OL + Nokia.

Comment: There may be an obvious answer to this one, If I ask geoserver through openlayers to return KML instead of png images will resolve the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  If you're going after google tiles, what does it have to do with geoserver?  I think you have an answer above to your original question. Maybe close this one as resolved, and start a new thread?

Comment: this is the best answer to all 3 (so far) of the questions about this on GIS.se